# Ввод строки в c++

Tags: c++, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я реализовал ввод строки?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class FirstClass
{
    protected:
        int str_size;
    public:
        char* str_value;

    FirstClass() {}

    FirstClass( int size ) {
        str_size = size;
        str_value = new char[str_size];
    }

    void set(char* value) {
        str_value = value;
    }

    char* get() {

        return str_value;
    }
};

int main() {
    FirstClass object(11);

    object.set("dddddddddd");

    printf("%s", object.get());

    return 0;
}
```

Выводит всё правильно и без ошибок.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под вводом строки? Я ожидал увидеть cin. А вместо `printf` в C++ используют cout.

Comment: @MichaelBelyakov Ввод значения через функцию

Comment: Как минимум, есть утечка памяти.

Comment: @aaa а точно не хотите использовать std::string?

Comment: @KoVadim Что знаю то и использую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, неправильно. Потому что вы как минимум теряете выделенную в конструкторе память, а сохраняете не саму строку, а указатель на нее.

Т.е., например, выполните

```
FirstClass object(1);
char s[] = "11111";
object.set(s);
object.get();
s[1] = '2';
object.get();
```

и вы увидите, что вывод - разный. Вряд ли это то, что вы хотите...

**Update**

```
void set(const char* value) {
    delete[] str_value;
    str_value = new char[strlen(value)+1];
    strcpy(str_value, value);
}

FirstClass(const char* value):str_value(nullptr)
{
    set(value);
}

~FirstClass() { delete[] str_value; }
```

Само собой, нужно в том же духе переписать оператор присваивания и копирующий конструктор...

Да, и

```
protected:
    int str_size;
public:
    char* str_value;
```

превратите в

```
private:
    char* str_value;
```

а

```
char* get() {
```

в

```
const char* get() {
```

Comment: Можете немножко подогнать под мой пример? Не совсем понятно

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбирать

Comment: Компилятор ругается: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Убрал в конструкторе то определение и всё заработало. Эта штука для старых компиляторов уже 2 раз с ошибкой.

Comment: nullptr - это для новых компиляторов. Если Ваш компилятор не понимает что это  - скорее всего нужно срочно менять компилятор.

Comment: @KoVadim Почему срочно? Скачал code blocks и mingw с сайта.

Comment: почему срочно? Вы же не изучаете на уроках английского старый английский 15 века? (если только не литературный критик того времени). 
Посмотрел на сайт codeblock -  там предлагают gcc 4.9.2. Задайте в настройках поддержку с++11 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler).

Comment: @koVadim Мне главное выполнить задание